# Cannot access LastAccessTime of file in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, fileinfo

Please see this image below:
[image]

How can i get value such as: LastAccesstime, LastWritetime, Length..v.v.. from Fileinfo fi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP the most suitable way to access files is through *StorageFiles* rather than directly by path. In this case you may take a look at [StorageFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh701737):

```
foreach (StorageFile contentStream in pickedFile)
{
    var prop = await contentStream.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
    DateTimeOffset lastModification = prop.DateModified;
    DateTimeOffset itemTime = prop.ItemDate;
    ulong size = prop.Size;
    //...
}
```

The problem with *FileInfo* is that in most cases you don't have privilege to access file via its path, whereas *StorageFile* works like a broker and file open picker grants privilege.